# Added programmatically UITabBarItem after switching app got crashed

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, forced-unwrapping

For existing UITabBarController already in storyboard do have Two TabBars (Home / Settings).

Now I added two more TabBarIems based on conditions based
(programVC / reportVC) i.e., `UIViewController`.

When Switching Tab programVC or reportVC app get crashed.

The `@IBOutlet var skeletonView: UIView!`  added in ProgramReportVC set to nil

```
class MainTabbarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addedConditionalTabs(isInserted: true)      
    }

// For existing tab inserted new tabs based on condition
func addedConditionalTabs(isInserted: Bool){
    if isInserted{
        let programVC = ProgramReportVC() // ProgramReportVC -> UIViewController
       programVC = “Program”
        let reportVC = ProgramReportVC()
       reportVC.screenTitle = “Report”

       programVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Program", image: UIImage(named: “ProgramImage”), tag: 2)
       reportVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Report", image: UIImage(named: “ReportImage”), tag: 3)

        self.viewControllers?.insert(programVC, at: 2)
        self.viewControllers?.insert(reportVC, at: 3)
    }

 }
```

s

**Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value**

How to resolved Unexpectedly found nil ?

programVC ->

```
@IBOutlet var skeletonView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var views: [UIView]!
@IBOutlet var subviews: [UIView]!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.showSkeleton()
  }


func showSkeleton() {
    self.skeletonView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
    self.view.addSubview(self.skeletonView)
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.skeletonView)
    let gradient = SkeletonGradient(baseColor: UIColor(named: "skeletonColor")!)
    let animation = SkeletonAnimationBuilder().makeSlidingAnimation(withDirection: .leftRight)
    self.skeletonView.isSkeletonable = true
    for items in views {
        items.isSkeletonable = true
    }
    for items in subviews {
        items.isSkeletonable = true
        items.showAnimatedGradientSkeleton(usingGradient: gradient, animation: animation)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is unrelated to the UITabBarController or how you're adding VCs to it. If a `UIView` that is `nil` gets force unwrapped (as is the case with your `skeletonView` IBOutlet), that will cause a crash regardless of whether the VC is presented by a tab controller or by something else.

Update: Based on the thread conversation, your issue is that you're accessing `skeletonView` inside of the `ProgramReportVC`'s `viewDidLoad` method. The VC's view will not have been initialized at that point in time, which also means its IBOutlets will not have been resolved yet.

My recommendation would be to call `showSkeleton()` in `viewDidAppear` instead, since UI updates in general are best done once the UI is actually visible on the screen.

Comment: I check its connected to Nib.

Comment: Inside of `ProgramReportVC`, are you accessing `skeletonView` before the nib has been loaded? For example, if you try to access it inside of `viewDidLoad` it will still be `nil`.

Comment: @mino yes I am loading inside  override func viewDidLoad() 
.

Comment: Can you post your `viewDidLoad` code for `ProgramReportVC`?

Comment: @Mino Updated my question for ViewDidLoad Code.

Comment: @kiran I've updated my answer as well! Adding an override of `viewDidAppear` and calling `showSkeleton()` in there should fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

```
if let programReportVC = UIStoryboard.identifier(.Dashboard).instantiateViewController(identifier: "ProgramReportVC") as? ProgramReportVC{
    // Do your Stuff here.
}
```

It's worked if added via like this.